# throwing/returning a 404 actionresult or exception in Asp.net MVC and letting IIS handle it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis-7

how do I throw a 404 or FileNotFound exception/result from my action and let IIS use my customErrors config section to show the 404 page?

I've defined my customErrors like so

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/trouble">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/notfound" />
</customErrors>
```

My first attempt at an actionResult that tries to add this doesnt work.

```
public class NotFoundResult : ActionResult {
    public NotFoundResult() {

    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = false;
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

But this just shows a blank page and not my /not-found page

:(

What should I do?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 introduced the [HttpNotFoundResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) action result which should be used in preference to manually throwing the exception with the http status code. 
This can also be returned via the [Controller.HttpNotFound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpnotfound%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method on the controller:

```
public ActionResult MyControllerAction()
{
   ...

   if (someNotFoundCondition)
   {
       return HttpNotFound();
   }
}
```

Prior to MVC 3 you had to do the following:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Had to demote this because one shouldn't be doing this by hand. Use the HttpNotFound Controller method as shown in another answer.

Comment: True - but HttpNotFound was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 3. This question (and my answer) pre-dates that and was an appropriate approach in earlier versions. I've now edited my answer to illustrate the newer approach which is preferred in MVC3.

Comment: Also, throwing an Exception is still reasonable sometimes, when you want to create a short, void, and reusable null check method for action parameter for example.

Comment: Actually upvoted both this answer and @ZoltánTamási. I find throwing `HttpException` particularly useful for furnishing re-usable assertive methods such as `var m = RequireValidModel(id)` where `RequireValidModel` is used in a lot of places and is intended to assert that a valid model should only ever be returned, else throw an exception back to any caller.

Additionally, you can leverage `HttpStatusCode` here by casting to `int` as follows: `throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid id")`

Comment: In .Net Core it changed again: `return new NotFoundResult();` or  `return new NotFoundObjectResult(string.Empty);`

Answer (score 6):

You can call Controller.HttpNotFound

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpnotfound(v=vs.98).aspx

```
if (model == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could help as well;

[ASP.NET MVC : Throwing 404 Exceptions Manually From Controller When Model is Null](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc---throwing-404-exceptions-manually-from-controller-when-model-is-null)

Comment: FYI this link no longer works and should be removed.